# Phantomjs 2.1.1 querySelectorAll() not able print innerHTML for all node list

Tags: phantomjs, nodelist

I am using phantom js 2.1.1 in windows 7.  I am trying to print all innerhtml of  list items.

**my code**

```
var nl =pageCv.evaluate(function(){
                return document.querySelectorAll("#main_tabs > ul >li");
            });
             console.log('main tab  Lenght :' + nl.length);
            for (var i=0; i<nl.length; i++) {
            console.log('id of ' + nl[i].innerHTML);    
            }
```

gettting this error

```
main tab  Lenght :3
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'nl[i].innerHTML')
```

How do I print all the innerHTML of node list? 
Please help me

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
var nl = pageCv.evaluate(function(s) {

var simpleArray = [],
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach,
    nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#main_tabs > ul >li");

    forEach.call(nodes, function(el){
        simpleArray.push(el.innerHTML);
    });
    return simpleArray;
}, 'something');

console.log('main tab  Lenght :' + nl.length);

for(var i=0; i < nl.length; i++)
{
  console.log(nl[i]);
};
```